# is pointer to base always <= pointer to derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I wonder if it's guaranteed by the C++ standard that *single* inheritance make the object "grow" upward, that is given a `class Base` and a `class Derived: public Base`, and a pointer `Derived* ptr`, the result of `dynamic_cast<Base*>(ptr)` will be always numerically smaller or equal to `ptr`.

Comment: I only recall that the relative ordering of member object addresses of the same access level is specified. I'm not sure if there is any guaranteed relation between member addresses and the address of the object itself...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you asking? Out of curiosity?

Comment: I am pushing some objects (which involve inheritance between them) as userdata to a Lua stack, so I have to deal with type erasure. And I wondered if I could assume that when retrieving the userdata back from the stack, I could assume that it would equal to the pointer to the `Base` class.

Comment: Note: even though you did not specify it, do make sure that there is no *virtual inheritance* involved. Things can really get awkward when it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Memory layout is implementation detail.

That being said, I'm not aware of any implementation that doesn't actually do that, assuming there are no virtual functions. If you *introduce* a virtual function in `Derived` (but there were none in `Base`), the virtual table pointer *could* (depending on the implementation) be placed before the `Base` fields (making the `Base*` greater than `Derived*`).

#### Clarification:

The example above is Visual C++ specific. You can check it out using the following code:

```
class Base {
    int X;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    virtual void f() {
    }
    int Y;
};

int main() {

    Derived d;
    Derived* d_ptr = &d;
    Base* b_ptr = dynamic_cast<Base*>(d_ptr); // static_cast would be enough BTW.

    bool base_smaller_or_equal = (ptrdiff_t)b_ptr <= (ptrdiff_t)d_ptr;

    return 0;

}
```

The `base_smaller_or_equal` will be `false` under Visual C++. Judging on @enobayram's comment, it should be `true` under GCC.

In any case, **it is an implementation detail** and not to be relied upon.

Comment: This is not the case with GCC. GCC puts the `vtable` pointer at the end of the layout of the derived class introducing `virtual` (or maybe just after the space for the base). The address of the derived object doesn't change in single inheritance. That said, this is probably an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

Comment: @enobayram: no, in this situation the v-pointer will be the first field. This is actually not only for gcc, but a requirement of the Itanium ABI. You can demonstrate it easily enough.

Comment: Curious, I've just tried to print the addresses out with GCC 4.6.1 and you're right. On my 32 bit system, I observe `&Derived + 4 == (Base *) &Derived`. I wonder what was different the last time I tried.

Answer (score 7):

No.

However, there is no need to panic yet. This kind of question, though not fully addressed in the Standard C++ is answered by the ABI document the compiler will follow. Many compilers such as gcc, Clang or icc (but *not* VC++) follow the [Itanium ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html).

In the Itanium ABI, as long as you have single non-virtual inheritance and the Base class has a virtual method, then Derived and Base will always have the same address.

That being said, this is an implementation you actually need not worry about. You can perfectly write C++ Standard compliant code and still manage your use cases. The thing is that C++ allows you to cast any pointer to `void*` and `char*` (the latter as a specific exception to non-aliasing) and back. The only thing you need to worry about is that when you case a `Base*` to a `void*` you need cast it back to a `Base*` and not a `Derived*`. That is, the type you put in and the type you get back should match.

It is much more difficult however to know (for sure) the size of an object. This requires the application of `sizeof` to the current dynamic type of the object and there is not facility to get it `virtually`.

My advice would be to actually instrument your base class so:

```
class Base {
public:
  char const* address() const { return (char const*)dynamic_cast<void const*>(this); }
  size_t offset() const { return this->address() - (char const*)this; }

  virtual size_t size() const { return sizeof(Base); } // to be overriden

  virtual ~Base() {}
};
```

This helps getting all the information you need ([see demo](http://ideone.com/eqYiZ)). Note that with the Itanium ABI `offset()` will always return `0`, but at least you are not *assuming* here.

Comment: It *is* a problem. Say you have an uninitialized storage of a good size (e.g. `char data[N]`) on which you _placement new_ construct the `Derived` class and then need _type erasure_ and only having knowledge about the `Base` class, can you assume that the address of the first byte in this storage (`&data[0]`) equals `Base*`? Given the answers here, I don't think you can assume that, which *is* worrying. You basically need to store an extra integer containing the pointer difference to be able to cast your `data` (above) into `Base*`, e.g. `reinterpret_cast<Base*>(data + the_different)`. Sadly.

Comment: @gustafr: This is a completely different problem, though. Even in the absence of inheritance, there is no guarantee that you can have a `struct X` stored in `data` and have your `X*` coincides with `&data` due to alignment. Indeed you need `N >= sizeof(X) + alignof(X) - 1`. In C++11 `std::aligned_storage<...>::type` comes to the rescue... however you still have the issue: even if you use `std::aligned_storage<N, alignof(Base)>::type` you have no guarantee that `Derived` has the same alignment as `Base`... use a `static_assert` or store the difference in a `uint8_t`.

Comment: In fact `aligned_storage` is my real use case, I just over-simplified with a `char[N]` for brevity.
So, even if you have properly aligned `Base`and `Derived` and use an `aligned_storage` to placement new it in, you won't be guaranteed that `&storage` is the `Base*`. I really don't think this is a different problem, just an edge case only few of us needs to worry about.

Comment: @gustafr: If you use `new (&storage) Derived(...)` then you are guaranteed under the Itanium ABI that `&storage` is a `Base*`. Other ABIs may guarantee it too, and you could always `assert` that your assumption holds.

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting, and highlights the problem that this guarantee is not in the language, if so many compilers can guarantee it anyway.
Any ideas on how to verify the support for this at compile time (e.g. to check for Itanium C++ ABI-frontend compiler macros)?

Comment: @gustafr: You'd have to know all the compilers that implement, or not, the Itanium ABI. If you can cast from `Derived` to `Base` at compile-time (`constexpr`), then a `static_assert` could work... you may want to ask that as a question of its own to get more options.