# luaL_checkudata inheritance checking

Tags: c++, lua

I have the following scenario:

One class named "Base" and second class named "Derived" which derives from "Base". I use metatables to support inheritance in Lua. However I need a solution for checking if passed userdata inherits from specified class.

```
static int BaseGetMyVar(lua_State *state)
{
    Base* base = *(Base**)luaL_checkudata(state, 1, "Base");
    //Base* base = *(Base**)lua_touserdata(state, 1);
    lua_pushinteger(state, base->GetMyVar());
    return 1;
}
```

When I pass "Derived" udata to this method I get:

```
HelloWorld.lua:17: calling 'getMyVar' on bad self (Base expected, got userd
ata)
```

How do I check inheritance? So I can pass either Base or Derived.

Current solutions I've found:

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-06/msg00000.html

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-04/msg00324.html

https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/auxiliar.c

Proposal by siffiejoe(Thanks)

https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-moon#moon_defcast

Another solution found by accident:

http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2013-06/msg00492.html

**My own solution(I like to own things )**

```
void* luaL_checkclass(lua_State *L, const char *classname, int objidx)
{
    if(!luaL_getmetafield(L, objidx, "__index"))
        return NULL;
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "__name");
    if(lua_type(L, -1) != LUA_TSTRING)
        return NULL;
    char const* basename = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 2);
    if(strcmp(basename, classname) != 0)
        luaL_typeerror(L, objidx, classname);
    return lua_touserdata(L, objidx);
}
```

I came up with my own idea. This requires metatable to have field __name(Lua 5.3 implements this, but you can still add this field on your own in previous versions).

More detailed:

Each metatable I register in Lua owns __index field which is either assigned to self or if it has a base class it is assigned to base class. The table at __index owns __name field which is the name of the class... we can just compare the names.

If we pass Derived object to Base method now it will work just fine.

Comment: Another one for your list: https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-moon#moon_defcast. The implementation is simliar to the LuaSocket one, but the `luaL_checkudata()` replacement automatically calls the registered function to cast the pointer to the correct type.

Comment: Thank you @siffiejoe (Philipp). I've added my own solution which works for me. If you have some suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-use a `lua_CFunction` for multiple related userdata
types, you have to overcome two problems:

### Accepting multiple userdata types

The [`luaL_checkudata()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_checkudata) function that is normally used for
type-safe access to a userdata's memory only checks for one specific
userdata type. All mentioned approaches therefore use a different
function to check the arguments of the `lua_CFunction`.

- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-06/msg00000.html
   proposes a clever naming convention so that a userdata of type
   `"A.B.C"` is assumed to also be a valid `"A.B"` userdata, and a
   valid `"A"` userdata. Checking is just a matter of comparing a
   prefix of the real type name with the requested userdata type
   name.
- http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2007-04/msg00324.html
   implements a function that basically calls `luaL_checkudata()`
   for multiple specified type names until one of those calls
   succeeds.
- https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/src/auxiliar.c
   (and
   https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-moon#moon_defcast
   as well) maintain a set of supported type names in the userdata's
   metatable. If the requested type doesn't match exactly, it's
   just an additional table lookup to check whether the type is
   supposed to be compatible.

  This is also the approach used in @Rochet2's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36070420/3677376) to this
   question, with an additional twist: It re-uses the chained `__index`
   metamethod tables to make the set of compatible types more manageable.

### Getting a proper pointer to the userdata's memory

Even when a userdata belongs to a group of related userdata types, the
memory layout of the different types is usually slightly different
(otherwise it wouldn't make much sense to use different userdata types
at all). So the second problem is to get a pointer that is compatible
with the requested userdata type.

Most of the approaches mentioned above ignore this problem because in
C you can get away with it if you are careful how you define your
related userdata types. The C standard guarantees that a pointer to a
`struct` has the same value as a pointer to its first member. So if
you have

```
 struct A { ... };
 struct B { A a; ... };
 struct C { B b; ... };
```

a pointer to `struct C` is automatically also a valid pointer to
`struct B` and `struct A`.

However if you cannot guarantee this particular memory layout, or if
you use C++ with multiple inheritance, or virtual inheritance, or just
an unfortunate choice of virtual methods (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10062606/3677376)),
you'll likely have to adjust the pointer values to make them valid as
pointers to a related userdata type.

https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-moon#moon_defcast
stores simple callback functions that you can use to adjust the
pointer value to the required type. E.g. for `class B : public A ...`
you would use `return (void*)(A*)(B*)p;` if `p` really is a `void`
pointer to a `B` object that should be passed to a function that
expects a `void` pointer to an `A` object.

### "Own" solution suggested in the question

The approach added in an edit to the question ignores problem 2. It
tries to solve problem 1 (identification of compatible userdata types)
by storing the userdata type name in the metatable (which also serves
as the `__index` metamethod). In Lua 5.3 the [`luaL_newmetatable()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_newmetatable)
function will do this for you. The given code snippet only works for
two cases:

1. A `Derived` userdata type uses the `Base` metatable as its
   `__index` metamethod, i.e. the derived userdata type does *not*
   have methods on its own, and so doesn't have its own `__index`.
2. For the `Base` object itself.

If you add more levels (e.g. a `MoreDerived` type), or if you need
methods specific to the `Derived` type, this simple approach won't
work anymore. You'd have to walk the `__index` metamethods chain
upward (assuming inheritance is handled using chained `__index`
metamethods) until you find the type name you are looking for.

Comment: Great explanation. There's one more solution but it's more manual method (only applicable if you have some kind of reflection system in your application). E.g. all classes derive from one main class named let's say "Object" , then you can just check with object->GetType() and cast to valid class.

Comment: I haven't really met with second problem yet so I don't understand it clearly. I would need some kind of example.

Comment: Let's use the multiple inheritance case: `class C: public A, public B {...}`. Now if you have a pointer to a `C` object cast to `void*` then *maybe* you can use the same pointer as a pointer to `A` (if the compiler puts `A` at the start of `C`), but using the `C` pointer value as a pointer to `B` will not work, because the memory reserved for the `B` part can't be at the same place as the memory for the `A` part. Usually the C++ compiler will adjust the pointer values if you do implicit conversion or casts, but with a `void*` it can't help you, because it doesn't know the real type.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way I can think of could be that the tables look like this:

```
Base = {Base = true}
Base.__index = Base
Derived = setmetatable({Derived = true}, Base)
Derived.__index = Derived

obj = setmetatable({}, Derived)
```

Now it is simple to check if obj inherits Base. You just do `obj.Base`
and this returns true if Base is inherited. In C you can use the methods `lua_setfield` and `lua_getfield` to set and get the value of the keys Base and Derived from the metatable.

There are multiple other ways to go about doing this.

Comment: I need C++ way(alternative to luaL_checkudata)

Comment: The code can be converted into C as well. I just felt that it was easier and clearer to show in lua what I mean.
Or do you mean that you do not want to store extra data to the Base and Derived tables? I added the C functions you can use.

Comment: I want to pass Derived as an arg and be able to check it using luaL_checkudata(state, 1, "Base");