# Lua checkudata type C++

Tags: c++, lua

I've been to the end of Google and back trying to solve this problem.

I have a few userdata objects that I push from C++ to Lua.
I have a function that should get the X value of either a 2D or 3D object.

When I try to get the userdata object, taking into consideration that it could be either a 2D element or 3D object, I need to be able to get the X for whichever the user chooses.

Here is what I tried:

```
int getX(lua_State* L)
{
    Object3D* a = static_cast<Object3D*>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Object3D"));
    if (!a)
    {
        Object2D* b = static_cast<Object2D*>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "Object2D"));
        if (b)
        {
            lua_pushnumber(L, b:getX());
        }
        else
        {
            lua_pushnil(L);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lua_pushnumber(L, a:getX());
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Unfortunately if the userdata type is not Object3D, it fails and exits on an lua error without continuing to try Object2D.
Therefore, it will only work in the above code if the object being passed is of type Object3D.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069204/lual-checkudata-inheritance-checking

Comment: I am not doing inheritance, this is for two completely separate classes. Reason being that I will be using the answer to this solution for more complex situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### [`luaL_testudata`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_testudata)
>
> `void *luaL_testudata (lua_State *L, int arg, const char *tname);`
>
> This function works like [`luaL_checkudata`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_checkudata), except that, when the test fails, it returns `NULL` instead of raising an error.

The `lua(L)_check*` functions throw Lua errors on failure, the `lua(L)_to*` functions return `NULL`.  For whatever reason, this one deviates from the naming convention and is named `lua(L)_test*` instead, which makes it a bit harder to find.

Your code is incomplete and doesn't compile as-is so I can't be bothered to check, but if I'm not mistaken, just replacing `luaL_checkudata` with `luaL_testudata` should make it work as intended.

Comment: Updated my code. Very interesting functions I didn't come across during my research. I solved the problem, but I will also give these a try. Thank you

Comment: @TreytenCarey Read the [reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html)! It is comparatively short and written in a way that's easy to follow. Reading the full thing should only take a few hours. Also take a look at [the headers](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/) (particularly [`lua.h`](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lua.h.html)) because they list functions ordered by purpose, not ordered by name.

Comment: Noted. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using rawequal to see which class the registry matches.